# How to create merge-sorted partitions in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I have two datasets with the same number of partitions; say 2 (it’s actually in the order of thousands, but for simplicity assume 2)

In my schema, I have two compulsory fields
userId and timestamp.

The partitioner works by calculating hash(userId) % numPartitions. And each partition is sorted on the composite (userId, timestamp) in ascending order.

I have saved both datasets as Parquet files in two different directories A and B.
Dataset in folder A has files A0.parquet and A1.parquet
Dataset in folder B has files B0.parquet and B1.parquet

My question(s) is/are:

1. How can I make sure, when I load the dataset A, spark always loads a single partition per file, i.e.

> Partition #0 => A/A0.parquet
>
> Partition #1 => A/A1.parquet

2. How can I make sure, when I load Datasets A and B together (either by means of union, or some other practical method of loading), I will still have 2 partitions, i.e.

> Partition #0 => mergeSorted(A/A0.parquet, B/B0.parquet)
>
> Partition #1 => mergeSorted(A/A1.parquet, B/B1.parquet)

Note: A previous version of this question was marked as a duplicate, being mistakenly confused about a question on HDFS partitions, I’m talking about Spark partitions here.
This definitely is not a duplicate; the essence of the question is about how to handle and merge partitions on Spark, not really how Spark utilizes HDFS partitions.
HDFS is just a storage layer, Spark partitions should be thought seperately from the HDFS partitions; and the answer to this can be thought of using local disk, NFS, EFS, s3 in mind...